# How to compose new string variable using bysort

Tags: stata

I want to prepare Stata code to generate new string variable as `suspect`  from identified `urid` on the basis of corresponding score less than or equal to 60 and missing score in each `said`.

Input:

```
primkey  ssuid  sup  urid  score
10312551  1255  601  122   60
10312552  1255  601  122   80
10312553  1255  601  123   90
10312554  1255  601  124   66
10312561  1256  601  122   40
10312562  1256  601  123   30
10312563  1256  601  124   .
10312564  1256  601  125   66
10312581  1258  602  126   80
10312582  1258  602  127   95
10312583  1258  602  127   100
10312584  1258  602  128   .
```

Output:

```
ssuid  sup  suspect
1255   601  122
1256   601  122,123,124
1258   602  128
```

The variables `primkey` and `score` fields are not required in output.

The following is the code that I have already tried:

```
sort state ssuid urid sup
gen x=_n
gen suspect=.
replace suspect=urid if (score <=60 | score==.) & urid=urid[x-1]
drop x
sort state ssuid suspect
gen x=_n
tostring suspect, replace
replace suspect=suspect[x-1]+","+suspect if suspect!="." & ssuid==ssuid[x-1]
drop x
gen x=strlen(ssususpect_sup)
gsort state ssuid -x
drop x
gen x=_n
replace suspect=suspect_sup[x-1] if ssuid==ssuid[x-1]
drop x

bys ssuid:gen x=_n 
keep if x==1
drop x
```

However, this is not producing the desired result.

Comment: Please read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/) for tips on how to improve your questions.

Comment: I have corrected my question. Thanks for correcting me...

Comment: Thanks for acceptance. I didn't (can't) find your bug, but some comments in the edited answer may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't make complete sense.

For `ssuid` 1255 the lowest score is 60. So, no score is less than 60.

For `ssuid` 1258 the lowest score is 80.

Stata's rule is that missing is arbitrarily large positive, so never less than 60.

It seems that your rule is less than or equal to 60 or missing.

With those fixes this works for me:

```
clear 
input primkey  ssuid  sup  urid  score
10312551  1255  601  122   60
10312552  1255  601  122   80
10312553  1255  601  123   90
10312554  1255  601  124   66
10312561  1256  601  122   40
10312562  1256  601  123   30
10312563  1256  601  124   .
10312564  1256  601  125   66
10312581  1258  602  126   80
10312582  1258  602  127   95
10312583  1258  602  127   100
10312584  1258  602  128   .
end 

egen tokeep = max(score <= 60 | missing(score)), by(ssuid) 
keep if tokeep 
drop tokeep 
drop if inrange(score, 61, .) 

bysort ssuid (primkey) : gen suspect = string(urid) if _n == 1 
by ssuid: replace suspect = suspect[_n-1] + ///
"," + string(urid) if _n > 1 & urid != urid[_n-1] 
by ssuid: keep if _n == _N 

keep ssuid sup suspect 
list 

     +---------------------------+
     | ssuid   sup       suspect |
     |---------------------------|
  1. |  1255   601           122 |
  2. |  1256   601   122,123,124 |
  3. |  1258   602           128 |
     +---------------------------+
```

EDIT Let's look at the original code. I have made some comments and found some code that can be slimmed and one clear bug, but I bailed out after that. Problems must be reproducible!

```
sort state ssuid urid sup
gen x=_n
gen suspect=.
replace suspect=urid if (score <=60 | score==.) & urid=urid[x-1]
drop x
sort state ssuid suspect
gen x=_n
tostring suspect, replace
replace suspect=suspect[x-1]+","+suspect if suspect!="." & ssuid==ssuid[x-1]
drop x
gen x=strlen(ssususpect_sup)
gsort state ssuid -x
drop x
gen x=_n
replace suspect=suspect_sup[x-1] if ssuid==ssuid[x-1]
drop x
bys ssuid:gen x=_n 
keep if x==1
drop x

*1 There is nothing in the data example about a variable -state-. 
* What do you don't show, we need not try to replicate 

*2 Your use of x for _n isn't needed. You can use _n directly. 
* That saves 8 lines 

sort ssuid urid sup
gen suspect=.
replace suspect=urid if (score <=60 | score==.) & urid=urid[_n-1]
sort ssuid suspect
tostring suspect, replace
replace suspect=suspect[_n-1]+","+suspect if suspect!="." & ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
gen x=strlen(ssususpect_sup)
gsort ssuid -x
drop x
replace suspect=suspect_sup[_n-1] if ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
bys ssuid: keep if _n == 1 

*3 Your first three lines can be slimmed to one 

by sort ssuid urid (sup) : gen suspect = urid if (score <=60 | score==.) & urid=urid[_n-1]
sort ssuid suspect
tostring suspect, replace
replace suspect=suspect[_n-1]+","+suspect if suspect!="." & ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
gen x=strlen(ssususpect_sup)
gsort ssuid -x
drop x
replace suspect=suspect_sup[_n-1] if ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
bys ssuid: keep if _n == 1 

*4 It's simpler to create -suspect- as string in the first place
* so cut the -tostring- line  

bysort ssuid urid (sup) : gen suspect = string(urid) if (score <=60 | score==.) & urid=urid[_n-1]
sort ssuid suspect
replace suspect=suspect[_n-1]+","+suspect if suspect!="." & ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
gen x=strlen(ssususpect_sup)
gsort ssuid -x
drop x
replace suspect=suspect_sup[_n-1] if ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
bys ssuid: keep if _n == 1 

*5 bug: testing for equality needs == not = 

bysort ssuid urid (sup) : gen suspect = string(urid) if (score <=60 | score==.) & urid==urid[_n-1]
sort ssuid suspect
replace suspect=suspect[_n-1]+","+suspect if suspect!="." & ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
gen x=strlen(ssususpect_sup)
gsort ssuid -x
drop x
replace suspect=suspect_sup[_n-1] if ssuid==ssuid[_n-1]
bys ssuid: keep if _n == 1 

*6 you refer to a variable -ssussusspect_sup- which you haven't supplied as 
* data, or created in your code. At this point I bail out.
```